# Changing the source php

Tags: php

I have a PAGE that displays the NAME of a radio programme: http://cidadehoje.pt/player/header.html
The NAME is given by a php file that change that NAME with each passing hour.

```
<?php
$time = date('H');
if($time < 07){
   echo 'PROGRAMME 1';
}else if($time >= 07 and $time < 12){
echo 'PROGRAMME 2';
}else if($time >= 12 and $time < 14){
echo 'PROGRAMME 3';
}else if($time >= 14 and $time < 19){
echo 'PROGRAMME 4';
}else if($time >= 19 and $time < 22){
echo 'PROGRAMME 5';
}else if($time >= 22 and $time < 24){
echo 'PROGRAMME 6';
}else{
echo 'PROGRAMME 7';
}
?>
```

What I need is put the PAGE changing the source php (wich contains the programme's names) with each day of the week.

For example:

If it is monday, the PAGE will use the "monday.php" like source of the porgramme's name.

```
<iframe src="http://cidadehoje.pt/player/**monday.php**"></iframe>
```

If it is tuesday, the PAGE will use the "tuesday.php" like source of the porgramme's name.

```
<iframe src="http://cidadehoje.pt/player/**tuesday.php**"></iframe>
```

And so on...

Can you help with this?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Have you considered looking at the manual pages of `date()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**`date`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to find the day of the week, using `l`.

```
<?php

echo "<iframe src='http://cidadehoje.pt/player/". strtolower(date('l')) .".php'></iframe>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably spend some time at php.net. It’s a great resource for everything PHP.
The function you want is date(). It has lots of parameters and one of them returns the day of the week.

Your code should look something like this:

```
$today = date(l);

<iframe src="http://cidadehoje.pt/player/$today.php"></iframe>
```